# Is it possible to constrain a path to a specific controller namespace?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have some controllers that I want to constrain to the path `/api/` like this:

```
server.com/api/Load/Test
```

For this I have set up this routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ApiDefault",
    url: "api/{controller}/{action}/",
    namespaces: new string[] { "Framework.ApiControllers" }
);
```

And of course the above url works, but so do `server.com/Load/Test` without `/api/`, and I would really like the api controllers to only respond to the `/api/` path.

How do I set up this?

Comment: Have you thought about using attribute routing directly on the controller, instead of defining a global route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution would be to move from convention based routing to attribute routing for your api controllers. That means removing your api route from your route configuration and add the route to your controller directly:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Load")]
public class LoadController : Controller
{

}
```

if you do not want to decorate each api controller individually, you can create a BaseApiController, that each of your api controllers can inherit from:

```
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
public class BaseApiController : Controller
{
}

public class LoadController : BaseApiController
{
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok("foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And after canoodling with attribute routing I'm pretty sure your code have an error and it should be `[Route("api/Load/{action}")]` :-)

Comment: Actually no. It worked locally without the action attribute and even if you'd like to add it, it should be `[action]` with brackets, not curly braces.

Comment: Then it must be differences between versions because it does not work on my 4.6.1 version. Also, not only did I need to specify action, it had to be in curly braces  o_O

Comment: Might be because I used .net core 2

Comment: Seems like a valid reason. I read about core, but didn't want to change to it now, maybe in the next project...